# Is there a way to read large content version with size greater than 100 MB in chunks?

Tags: apex, contentversion

I'm planning to upload files from content version to other webservice that I don't own, the other service provide resumable API that takes only 320 KB per chunk, so Is there a way to split the blob that I got from content version in chunks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not in Apex. You'd be limited by the heap size of Apex. You would need an external service to read the file, instead. For example, you could write a Heroku service to call the Salesforce REST API, then do the chunking/sending on the Heroku side.

Comment: I tried to query the version data and I got this error through workbench "Unknown Asynchronous State", so for example If I want to build external service then I should use external link for the file to stream?

Comment: @user1391482 You would use the [sObject Blob Retrieve](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_sobject_blob_retrieve.htm) function to get the file content via the REST API. Note that this isn't a query, you need to do that first if you don't have the ID. Note that even if you include VersionData in the query, you'd only get a URL (which would be the REST URL from above).